# What would be a good translation of 'nitpick'?

Tags: traducción

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nitpick#English) defines '**nitpick**' as

> 1. To correct minutiae or find fault in unimportant details; to kvetch.

I have found several translations, but I'm not sure at all of which to use.

> - Fijarse en pequeñeces, criticar cualquier cosa por inconsecuente que
>     sea, encontrar errores por todas partes, poner atención a cosas
>     inconsecuentes, preocuparse en exceso de detalles inconsecuentes, ser
>     demasiado escrupuloso
> - Criticar por gusto, criticar por cosas inconsecuentes
> - Sacarle faltas a todo; buscarle tres pies al gato
> - encontrarle tres pies al gato
> - ser un tiquismiquis
> - [Ar] encontrarle la quinta pata al gato, encontrarle el pelo al huevo

With so many different translations, it seems that none fits exactly, and that there may be regional differences. What would be the most commonly used?

Additionally: **what would be the translation for the *noun* ('a nitpick')?**

Answer (score 5):

I would go for **quisquilloso**, since it matches the meaning and it is used quite commonly (at least in Spain):

> [**quisquilloso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UwnSlDz)
>   1. adj. **Que se para en quisquillas (‖ pequeñeces**). U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Demasiado delicado en el trato común. U. t. c. s.
>   3. adj. Fácil de agraviarse u ofenderse con pequeña causa o pretexto. U. t. c. s.

Yes, I know you are looking for a noun and this is an adjective but you can easily say *eres un quisquilloso*.

From the references you write in your question, there is another one I would use for this situation:

> [**tiquismiquis**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZpqQlna)
>   *Tb. tiquis miquis.*
>   Del lat. macarrónico tichi michi, alterac. del lat. mediev. tibi, michi 'para ti, para mí'; en lat. tibi, mihi.
>   1. m. pl. **Escrúpulos o reparos vanos o de poquísima importancia.**
>   2. m. pl. coloq. Expresiones o dichos ridículamente corteses o afectados.
>   3. m. y f. Persona que hace o dice tiquismiquis. U. t. c. adj.

WordReference mentions many possible [synonyms to quisquilloso](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/quisquilloso):

- cascarrabias
- delicado
- enojadizo
- escrupuloso
- meticuloso
- minucioso
- picajoso
- provocador
- puntilloso
- reparón
- sermoneador
- susceptible

Maybe I am a bit *quisquilloso*, but none of them satisfies me: they lose part of the meaning (feel free to ask about any of them if you want clarifications).

Comment: @user _tiquismiquis_ is a noun, so we would say _ser un tiquismiquis_. Since _quisquilloso_ is an adjective, we would say _ser quisquilloso_.

Comment: A "quisquilla" is a "shrimp", and a "nit" is a "louse", so I find this translation quite satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just a nitpick to [fedorqui's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18531/12637) :-) The first word I thought of when reading "nitpick" was *puntilloso* (a word that he discarded). In Spanish we have:

> **[puntilloso, sa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UgE1IxP)**
>
> De *puntillo* y *-oso*.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que es muy **minuciosa y concienzuda**, a veces **hasta la exageración**, en lo que hace.
> 2. adj. Suspicaz, quisquilloso.

But once again, this is an adjective and not a noun, and it is applied to a person (as is *tiquismiquis*). For a word that could apply to define the minor correction itself, I would say

> **[menudencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OxbxPcl)**
>
> De *menudo* y *-encia*.
>
> 1. f. Pequeñez de algo.
> 2. f. **Exactitud, esmero y escrupulosidad con que se considera y reconoce algo, sin omitir lo más menudo y leve**.
> 3. f. Cosa de poco aprecio y estimación.

And also:

> **[pequeñez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SWXT6Iv)**
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de pequeño.
> 2. f. Infancia, corta edad.
> 3. f. **Cosa de poco momento, de leve importancia**.

So, "a nitpick" could be "una pequeñez, una menudencia" or even "una [minucia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PKdGCwn)". As for the verb, it is not present in the DRAE and is very little used as it is an invented verb, but you could use *minuciosear*:

> *Como en el Santiago Bernabéu, aunque con menos cámaras encima para **minuciosear** su reacción, Caparrós se estiró de los pelos cuando el colegiado le perdonó la expulsión a Jonny.*
>
> - [Enlace](http://www.superdeporte.es/levante/2014/03/15/sigue-levante-celta-directo/220076.html).