# ¿Qué significa este proverbio? "Yo dueña y vos doncella, ¿quién barrerá la casa?"

Tags: proverbios

¿A qué se refiere este proverbio?

> Yo dueña y vos doncella, ¿quién barrerá la casa?

Comment: Hola Armin y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. ¿Qué te sugiere a ti? ¿Qué resultados encontraste al realizar una búsqueda? Es importante mostrar tus esfuerzos para que nosotros nos esforcemos en ayudarte :)

Comment: No lo se todavia! esta fue la razon que lo he preguntado aqui! solo lo vi en un mensaje.

Comment: Pero digo yo que sabrás realizar búsquedas en google antes de preguntar cualquier duda que te surja :)

Comment: Si, por ejemplo aqui: "https://los-proverbios.com/yo-duena-y-vos-doncella-quien-barrera.html" pero no hay la respuesta de su definicion o uso!

Comment: Armin, bienvenido. Fedorqui tiene razon. Puede que una busqueda de google no te lleve a un resultado "directo" con una explicacion detallada, pero buscando un poco mas o de distinta manera se resuelven muchas preguntas basicas como esta. He puesto una respuesta solo para que veas que con un par de busquedas en el diccionario puedes entender los terminos clave y deducir el significado de la expresion. No pretendemos ser [tiquismiquis](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18530/5481) con las preguntas, pero parte de enseñar es enseñar a usar las herraminetas basicas, como un diccionario o google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dueña` es un término algo obsoleto para referirse a quien esta al cargo de otros: En [el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EEsL9LT)

> Amo de la casa, respecto de sus criados.

y `doncella` viene a [ser lo opuesto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E897H8U):

> Criada que sirve cerca de la señora, o que se ocupa en los menesteres domésticos ajenos a la cocina.

Así que el refrán dice "Yo soy el jefe y tú estás a mis órdenes. ¿Quién piensas que va a barrer la casa, tú o yo?".

Como puede leerse en [este enlace](https://books.google.com/books?id=jIcUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=Yo+due%C3%B1a+y+vos+doncella,+%C2%BFqui%C3%A9n+barrer%C3%A1+la+casa?&source=bl&ots=0ZrWIJftAr&sig=CkJzrKEQuMNkhgHdVO5LU1Wb5_o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj27rCpz6jRAhWC7IMKHQaRCecQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q=Yo%20due%C3%B1a%20y%20vos%20doncella%2C%20%C2%BFqui%C3%A9n%20barrer%C3%A1%20la%20casa%3F&f=false):

> cada uno debe cumplir con las obligaciones de su estado [estatus] o ministerio, sin pretender cargarlas a otro.

Es parecido a otro refrán que dice que "donde manda patrón no manda marinero".